# How to plot the SEAc ellipses - SIBER package?

Tags: r, plot

I'm working with a dataframe that has group and community information, however I have a small sample size of each category of some groups (<10 samples):

```
`iso1   iso2   group   community
-17.2  9.80   2019    male
-18.9  10.01  2020    female
-17.0  9.67   2019    female
-16.8  9.20   2021    male
...`
```

So I'm trying to plot the SEAc ellipses thar are corrected for small sample sizes, but I'm having the following problems:

This is the basic plot code given in the package, but it plots the SEA ellipses only as far as I know.

```
`plotSiberObject(phaet,
            ax.pad = 2, 
            hulls = F, community.hulls.args, 
            ellipses = T, group.ellipses.args,
            group.hulls = F, group.hull.args,
            bty = "L",
            iso.order = c(1,2),
            xlab=expression({delta}^13*C~'permille'),
            ylab=expression({delta}^15*N~'permille'),
            cex = 0.5)
addEllipse(mu, Sigma, m = 134, n = 100, p.interval = NULL,
       ci.mean = FALSE, small.sample = TRUE, do.plot = TRUE)`
```

I find this function add Ellipse that should be possible to plot the SEAc ellipses, but it plots only a small ellipse in the plot - the smallest black one (and I have five groups categories and two community categories, so it should give me ten corrected ellipses).

[image]

I tried using ggplot2 but then I found in the page of  the package that this function is not available for ggplot yet.
I hope to find how to plot the SEAc ellipses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working through this right now with my own data. Here's the solution I found.
The 'addEllipse' function only plots singular ellipses at a time, which is why you only see the addition of one new ellipse.

Instead, what you will want to do is use the 'plotGroupEllipses' function within which 'plot.args' is what will enable you will to list the arguments you want to have passed on to 'addEllipse' including 'small.sample=T'. Something like this:

```
plotSiberObject(phaet,
            ax.pad = 2, 
            hulls = F, community.hulls.args, 
            ellipses = T, group.ellipses.args,
            group.hulls = F, group.hull.args,
            bty = "L",
            iso.order = c(1,2),
            xlab=expression({delta}^13*C~'permille'),
            ylab=expression({delta}^15*N~'permille'),
            cex = 0.5)    
plotGroupEllipses(phaet, plot.args = list(n = 100,
                                          p.interval = NULL,
                                          ci.mean = F, 
                                          small.sample = T, 
                                          do.plot = T,
                                          lty = 1, lwd = 2),
              iso.order = c(1,2))
```

If you run this you will see that this adds ellipses to your existing plot. If you only want SEAc ellipses, make sure to set 'hulls', 'ellipses', and 'group.ellipses' to 'F' to create a base scatter plot on top of which you SEAc ellipses will be added. Hope this helps!